# How to load a language file from a package in fuelphp?

Tags: php, fuelphp

Using the config.php `always_load` configuration, how does one load a language file from a package?

All of the fuelphp documentation alludes to being able to do this, but only shows the syntax for loading from a module.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

fuel/app/config/config.php

```php
'always_load' => [
    'language' => [
        // loads fuel/app/lang/en/login.php into login group
        'login',
    ],
],
```

fuel/app/config/production/config.php

```php
'always_load' => [
    'language' => [     
        // override /config/config.php with contents from
        // /fuel/packages/pkg/lang/en/login.php
        'lang_file_from_package' => 'login',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are core extensions, which means it will merge the contents of the files found in app and in the package.

As such, there is no method to define you want to load it from the package only, other then by specifying a fully qualified pathname, which will always load just that file.